# Remove all listeners for Activity before changing to another Activity

Tags: android, android-activity, listener

I use a lot of animation in a current Android app - I hook AnimationListener to them and thus control the flow. I also use some listeners for sounds and so on also for flow control.
When changing to another activity halfways through some of these animations/sounds, some of these listeners cause crashes because the listeners call code after the activity itself has ended/been deallocated. Is there anyway to force all animations on a certain view (ViewGroup really) for an activity to be removed? The same goes for any sound objects (using MediaPlayer). As for the ViewGroup, this would have to be done recursively on all contained views. Or is there another simpler way of doing this?

Here is my recursive function so far. I call it before going to another Activity. I call it on the Activity's top ViewGroup. Can be a RelativeLayout, LinearLayout or whatever else. The LEVEL is just for testing and not important.

```
private void clearAnimationsInViewgroup(ViewGroup viewgroup, final int LEVEL) {
    final int CHILDRENCOUNT = viewgroup.getChildCount();
    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "LVL" + LEVEL + ", clearAnimationsInViewgroup: " + viewgroup + ", having child count: " + CHILDRENCOUNT);
    View view;
    Animation animation;
    for (int i = 0; i < CHILDRENCOUNT; i++) {
        view = viewgroup.getChildAt(i);
        // "View" can be a subclass "ViewGroup"?
        if (view instanceof ViewGroup) {
            ViewGroup childViewgroup = (ViewGroup)view;
            clearAnimationsInViewgroup(childViewgroup, LEVEL + 1);
        }
        animation = view.getAnimation();
        if (animation != null) {
            Log.d(LOG_TAG, "LVL" + LEVEL + " clearing anim listener");
            animation.setAnimationListener(null);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: may be you can check if the activity still exists before performing an operation. in that way it wont crash atleast.

Comment: Just check if not null and stop them all in the `onPause()` of the activity

Comment: It's not really feasible because the activity contains lots of animations and codes and I'd probably just break something doing such huge amount of changes. I wrote a recursive function doing checks on a ViewGroup and all its children View:s. Some of the View:s are ViewGroup:s too, so I go recursive on them. I think it works. I set animation listeners to null on views having animation set. I'll attack the mediaplayers next...